# Custom Delegate causing errors on button tap

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mvvm, delegates

I'am working on a simple `tableView` project on swift with MVVM architecture. But when I tap a button on that tableView I'am getting an error like this:

**Thread 1: Simultaneous accesses to 0x7faf490331c8, but modification requires exclusive access**

I have defined a model like this

```
struct Person{
    var name: String
    var username : String
    var currentFollowing : Bool
    let image : UIImage?
}
```

There is a custom delegate protocol

```
protocol  PersonFollowingTableViewCellDelegate : AnyObject {
    
    func PersonFollowingTableViewCell( _ cell: PersonFollowingTableViewCell, didTapWith  : Person)
}
```

Using which I'am trying to configure a button

```
 @objc private func didTapButton(){
        let defaultPerson = Person(name: "default", username: "default", currentFollowing: true, image: nil)
        person?.currentFollowing = !(person?.currentFollowing ?? true)
        delegate?.PersonFollowingTableViewCell(self, didTapWith: person ?? defaultPerson )
        prepareForReuse()
        configure(with: person ?? defaultPerson)
    }
```

The callback Method in ViewController is here

```
extension ViewController : PersonFollowingTableViewCellDelegate{
    func PersonFollowingTableViewCell(_ cell: PersonFollowingTableViewCell, didTapWith array: Person) {
        return
    }
```

Comment: have you added anything inside prepareForReuse()?

Comment: Yes. initialised all values to nil

Comment: try to comment this and check

Comment: Still same Error

Comment: This error suggests a threading problem. Do you have any code that does processing on a background thread/GCD queue?

Comment: (If you use any code that beings `DispatchQueue`... or `Thread`, that is a likely culprit.

Comment: @DuncanC Thank you .no I dont have any such method. Problem was in didTapButton() . Solved right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your @objc private func didTapButton().
Instead of

```
person?.currentFollowing = !(person?.currentFollowing ?? true)
```

make

```
let currentFollowing = !(person?.currentFollowing ?? true)
person?.currentFollowing = currentFollowing
```